# Where multiples condiciones c# y ef core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Tengo el siguiente problema y es que cuando un registro no tiene la lista de **RequestAssignments** no me trae el join y no me trae ese registro, quiero que me traiga el join aunque esa lista sea null y si no es null entonces pueda filtrar por los datos que tenga esa lista en el where de multiples condiciones

```
 var query = _mapper
                .ProjectTo<WorkTrayVm>(
                _unitOfWork
                .Requests
                .GetAllById(
                    a => !a.DeletedRecord
                    &&
                    (request.RequestNo == null || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.RequestNo) || a.RequestNo.ToLower().Contains(request.RequestNo.ToLower())))
                    &&
                    (!request.TypeId.HasValue || a.TypeId == request.TypeId)
                    &&
                    (!request.RefferalChanelId.HasValue || a.ReferralChannelId == request.RefferalChanelId)
                    &&
                    (!request.StateId.HasValue || a.StatusId == request.StateId)
                    &&
                    (!request.DateFrom.HasValue || a.EntryDate >= request.DateFrom)
                    &&
                    (!request.DateTo.HasValue || a.EntryDate <= request.DateTo)
                    &&
                    (a.RequestPeople.Any(aa => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.ComplaintNumber) || aa.People.Number.ToLower() == request.ComplaintNumber.ToLower())))
                    &&
                    (a.RequestAssignments.Any(aa => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Assgments) || aa.Assigned.Email.ToLower() == request.Assgments.ToLower())))                    
                    , false, false, request.PageNumber, request.PageSize))
                   .OrderByDescending(a => a.Id)
                   .ToList();
```